# Rearrange unnecessarily calls the inline jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have arrangeable widgets on my page (using JQuery sortable), each of them have their own "reference".

They also contains  `$(document).ready()` at the end of the widgets :

```
            <script>
                {# Handle elements #}
                $(document).ready( function () {
                    var el = $(widget.[{{ section }}][{{ index }}]);
                    widget.add($(el));
                });
            </script>
```

Theoretically the `$(document).ready()` only runs once and that's when the page loads. The issue is that it also runs when an element is dragged and dropped.

In all honesty all of you who recommended avoiding inline JS are right. In this particular case I have a good cause to put inline JS there.

Am I right in thinking that it should not run on drag and drop? If not, what solutions are there to prevent it from doing so?

Update: simple example is here:

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/4aFsY/1/)

Try to rearrange the 1st, 3rd and 6th element and check the console.

Comment: I don't think it should run, but than again, there might be a script that reloads the widget?

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle link?

Comment: On the arrangement, the references are changing on the inside elements with a (regular expression) replace function, but that's all.

Comment: Ideally you should not be using ``<script>`` tags throughout your document. Your js should be in a separate file (or separate module files) that you load into the document.

Comment: You said, ideally. In this case I have two types of rearrangement:
1. rearrange widgets ;
2. rearrange elements in the widget. 

I need to have this script inside the widget. In the example it's an adding function, but in my code it use a data (pre)populating.

Comment: Well that all depends on what's doing the *dragging and dropping* and how this works?

Comment: I'm going to add a jsfiddle link soon.

Comment: jsfiddle is there now.

Comment: Nick, you were right. I removed from the document, created a jquery function outside, and it started to work properly.